# R Separate column based on pattern

Tags: r, tidyr

My dataset looks like this -

```
dataset = data.frame(Comments=c('Wow... Loved this place.   1','Crust is not good.  0','Not tasty and the texture was just nasty.   0'))
```

I'm trying to split the dataset into two columns such that the first column contains **only the text** and the second column contains the **only the number at the end of each string.**

Here's my attempt

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dataset = dataset %>%
  separate(Comments, into = c("Comment", "Score"), sep = " (?=[^ ]+$)")
```

However I'm not getting a perfect separation. I've looked at other solutions online, but no luck yet.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you split on a period followed by >1 space? From your example dataset, that would work here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could use `substr` and `gsub`

```
dataset <- dataset %>%
  mutate(Comments = as.character(Comments)) %>%
  mutate(Score = substr(Comments, nchar(Comments), nchar(Comments))) %>%
  mutate(Comment = gsub("\\s\\d", "", Comments))
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to take advantage of `stringr` functions:

```
dataset %>% 
  mutate(Score = str_extract_all(Comments, pattern = "[:digit:]"), 
         Comments = str_remove_all(Comments, pattern = "[:digit:]") %>% str_trim())

#                                   Comments Score
#1                  Wow... Loved this place.     1
#2                        Crust is not good.     0
#3 Not tasty and the texture was just nasty.     0
```